# Plot the trajectory of vectors in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vector, plot, numerical-integration

I have created the following data in MATLAB as an example, using the x and y axes:

```
t = 1:5    % time in seconds

dxx = [10,8,6,5,4] % speed in x direction
w = trapz(t,dxx)   % distance object in x direction (numerical integration)

dyy = [9,7,6,5,3]  % speed in y direction
c = trapz(t,dyy)   % distance of object in y direction (numerical integration)
```

How can I plot the vectors dxx(t) vs dyy(t) (the net trajectory at time t), using only this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I assume you need [**`cumtrapz`**](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/cumtrapz.html) instead of `trapz`.
For plotting you can use [**`quiver`**](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/quiver.html)

```
t = 1:5    % time in seconds

dxx = [10,8,6,5,4] % speed in x direction
w = cumtrapz(t,dxx)   % distance object in x direction (numerical integration)

dyy = [9,7,6,5,3]  % speed in y direction
c = cumtrapz(t,dyy)   % distance of object in y direction (numerical integration)

quiver(w,c,dxx,dyy)
```

resulting in:

[image]

Is it what you are looking for?